# Redirect specific page on specific domain alias to https/SSL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Redirect specific page on specific domain alias to https/SSL.

The webhosting is setup with multiple domain aliases on the same vhost.
It needs to redirect a specific page on a specific domain alias to https.

- domain-a.com
- domain-b.com
- domain-c.com

http://www.domain-c.com/contact needs to redirect to             https://www.domain-c.com/contact

The other domains, domain-a.com and domain-b.com don't need to redirect     /contact to https

Comment: .htaccess is the preferred way

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup the most efficient way to do this would be in the code of the web page.

In php you could use the example below:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == ""){
 $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
 header("Location: $redirect");
}
```

But other options are also possible. For example for IIS you could make a rule in the `web.config` to match the certain page and redirect it to HTTPS.

Basic redirection in a `.htaccess` should work for you then.

```
redirect /contact https://www.domain-c.com/contact
```

There are prettier ways to do this in a .htaccess file but don not have an environment to test it before posting.

Comment: Having some more information would make it easier to help you in your situation.